# Download only the first portion (of unknown length) of a web page using C#

Tags: c#, .net, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I'm writing a personal app that scrapes data from a website. It currently pulls entire pages before analyzing them and these pages can range from 300 - 600 KiB. The 10 pages that I tested against total up to 4 MiB. The page contains dynamic content so I don't know exactly where the data starts at. I do have delimiters so that I know where the data is at once I've scanned the page. Is there any way to only download up to the portion that I need? This would cut the total download down to 2 MiB for those 10 pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example, where you read from a stream until you match a 10 byte delimiter which matches your own. Although the specifics are up to you to handle, I think this represents an easy method to achieve what you want.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com");
using (var resp = request.GetResponse())
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        char[10] block;
        sr.ReadBlock(block, 0, 10);
        if (block.CharEquals(myDelim))
            break;
        sb.Append();
    }
}
// Process the StringBuilder here.
```

Please note that `CharEquals` is an extension method that simply compares if two character arrays are equal - there's nothing special to it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `WebRequest` instead of a `WebClient`, then you can retrieve only the data from the stream that you need:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    //..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that just require you to change your logic from scraping all the pages and processing them to find the data -> to reading a page, process and if it is does not contain the data you want, then proceed with next page?

With more knowledge on the context, you can custom the way your code crawl the pages so that it is optimal by crawling the most likely pages for the data for best result.